# XCode: Displaying 5 rows of a database in labels

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sqlite

I am using XCode 6.4 and Swift 2.2.

I have a leaderboard that I would like to display to my screen through labels. Currently, I can successfully write and read the database through my app, but it just prints the contents of my database to the xcode terminal. I would like to print those contents to labels on my screen. Any idea how I could get this done? I'm not exactly sure I can loop through the labels, so maybe I need to change the logic.

I am using [SQLiteDB](https://github.com/FahimF/SQLiteDB)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class FinishTestController: UIViewController {
// MARK: Properties
var highscore:Int?
var finishtime:String?
let db = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance()


@IBOutlet weak var correctAnswers: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Time: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var FirstScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var FirstTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var SecondScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var SecondTime: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addhighscore()
    loadhighscores()
}

func addhighscore(){
    db.execute("INSERT INTO EASY_MATH5 (Score, Time) Values ('\(highscore!)', '\(finishtime!)'); ", parameters:nil)
}

func loadhighscores(){
    var result = db.query("SELECT * from EASY_MATH5 ORDER BY Score DESC, Time ASC LIMIT 5", parameters: nil)
    println("===============================")
    for row in result
    {
        //**Print database to labels
        FirstScore.text = row["Score"]!.asString()
        FirstTime.text = row["Time"]!.asString()

        //Print database to terminal
        print(row["Rank"]!.asString())
        print(" ")
        print(row["Score"]!.asString())
        print(" ")
        println(row["Time"]!.asString())
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    correctAnswers.text = "Score: \(highscore!)"
    Time.text = "Time: \(finishtime!)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func Menu(sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goestoMenu", sender: self)
}



}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a `UITableView` instead of different labels. You could create a cell to represent `time & score`

Comment: I agree with kye. Table views are the easiest way to build a dynamic list of labels. You can also check the GRDB library: it knows how to feed table view from an SQLite database: https://github.com/groue/GRDBDemo

Comment: Thanks for the library recommendation, I'll try that!